# Calling a Subform of Startup

Tags: python, wxpython

```
class MyDialog(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        self.no_resize = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(500, 450),style = self.no_resize)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, size=(250, 270))
        self.combo = wx.ComboBox(self.panel, -1, pos=(60, 100))

        #call settings form here

        self.start_read_thread()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def read_employees(self,read_file):
        emp_list = []
        with open(read_file) as f_obj:
            for line in f_obj:
                emp_list.append(line)
        wx.CallAfter(self.combo.Append, emp_list)

    def start_read_thread(self):
        filename = 'employees.txt'
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
            executor.submit(self.read_employees, filename) 

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyDialog(None, "Messaging App")
app.MainLoop()
```

**Problem:**

When the program loads for the first time on the users machine, it will open a settings menu that prompts for the e-mail/password. Without filling out the settings menu, the program is of no use, so calling the settings subform and having the user configure it is necessary. In subsequent startups, it will just read the data in from the file.

Should I call the settings subform from the `__init__` `constructor` directly, or another thread and pass the data? I'm still learning threading, but to me, it seems like overkill for a simple subform to gather the data.

Any time afterward, the user can on the settings menu and access that same subform to update the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seem like overkill.
Without knowing exactly what your plans are, I'd run with something simple like this.

```
import wx
import os
class MyDialog(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        self.no_resize = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(500, 450),style = self.no_resize)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, size=(250, 270))
        self.emp_list = []
        e_name = 'employees.txt'
        if os.access(e_name, os.R_OK):
            with open(e_name,'r') as f_obj:
                for line in f_obj:
                    self.emp_list.append(line.strip())
        else:
            #Call employees.txt setup routine here
            frame = SetUp(parent=self)

        self.combo = wx.ComboBox(self.panel, -1,choices=self.emp_list, pos=(60, 100))
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

class SetUp(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, "Setup employee data", size= (280,130))
        self.parent=parent
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.emp_panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.employee_name = wx.TextCtrl(self.emp_panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Input Employee Name",size=(200,25))
        self.emp_button = wx.Button(self.emp_panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Add")
        self.emp_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.AddEmp)
        close_button = wx.Button(self.emp_panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Close")
        close_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)
        sizer.Add(self.employee_name)
        sizer.Add(self.emp_button)
        sizer.Add(close_button)
        self.emp_panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()

    def AddEmp(self,event):
        e_name = 'employees.txt'
        emp_name = self.employee_name.GetValue()
        with open(e_name,'a') as f_obj:
            f_obj.write(emp_name+"\n")
    def OnClose(self,event):
        e_name = 'employees.txt'
        if os.access(e_name, os.R_OK):
            with open(e_name,'r') as f_obj:
                for line in f_obj:
                    self.parent.combo.Append(line.strip())
        self.Close()

app = wx.App()
frame = MyDialog(None, "Messaging App")
app.MainLoop()
```

It's very rough and ready but I am running of time to do other things.
Hopefully it will help

Comment: I think you misunderstood ;) Don't worry, let me clarify. I'm talking about a subform, let's say settings, that pop-ups the first time the user runs the program, and they have to configure certain paths for storage, do I launch the subform directly from the `__init__` or a separate thread? If they  don't configure the settings, program is useless. The best way I can explain, is if you've used Thunderbird, when you first start the program it asks if you want to use an existing e-mail or create one. Once you select an option, it doesn't prompt you again, unless you go to the settings menu.

Comment: I didn't think that I had to do more than put the comment #Call employees.txt setup routine here in. See my edited answer